# special cronjob scheduling

Tags: linux, cron

I have three scripts and want every one of them to run every 3 minutes, but in way that every minute a different script is running.

for example

```
00:00 script1 is executed
00:01 script2 is executed
00:02 script3 is executed
00:01 script1 is executed
```

Is there a way to make this work via crontab in Debian?

At the moment I have it like this:

```
*/3 * * * * php /Scripts/script1.php &> /dev/null
*/3 * * * * php /Scripts/script2.php &> /dev/null
*/3 * * * * php /Scripts/script3.php &> /dev/null
```

but this would run all the scripts all 3 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a wrapper script every minute.
This wrapper script looks at (minutes % 3) and calls the correct script using the remainder.
Only one line in cron: nice.

EDIT: New thoughts
You can skip the wrapper by introducing an ugly crontab line.
I would go for the wrapper (cleaner crontab, place to set and export variables,
additional control statements), but I think you should know about the possibilities.
Make the testfiles x0, x1 and x2 in /tmp, chmod +x them, with the content

```
echo $(date) $0 >> /tmp/x.out
```

Make a crontab line

```
* * * * * /tmp/x`echo "$(date '+\%M') \% 3" | bc`
```

Wait 5 minutes (maybe get coffee black for me?) and look at /tmp/x.out.
Remove the crontab entry and the new /tmp/x* files.

Answer (score 2):

There might be fancier ways, but the dead simple way is just to list out the minutes you want them to run on (and the rest would of course be * for hours, days, etc):

```
0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27...
1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28...
2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29...
```